# Not able to retrieve image id from sibling site within a switch_to_blog

Tags: images, switch-to-blog

Here is how I am trying to grab the image id for 'white_logo'.

```
switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);
echo attachment_url_to_postid( get_theme_mod('white_logo'));
restore_current_blog();
```

The echo is printing '0'. It seems that when I use 'attachment_url_to_postid' for grabbing IDs of images that are within the current site's media library that it works. But when I try to grab IDs of images within other sites media libraries I'm not getting the desired response.
Is there an alternative way to achieve this? Thank you!

EDIT NOTE:
I should add that I do know the 'switch_to_blog' is working properly as I am able to get the image url with 'get_theme_mod()'. I'm just unable to retrieve the ID with 'attachment_url_to_postid()'.

Comment: I have hit this wall as well with a personal project.  I am wondering if it is a known issue... maybe look in wordpress's git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind this is only going to get you the image ID, but it should do the trick... does in my circumstance at least.

```
// switch to the correct blog
switch_to_blog( $site -> blog_id );

// pull in our db global
global $wpdb;

// get the image ID
$_image_id = $wpdb -> get_col( $wpdb -> prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", get_theme_mod( 'white_logo' ) ) );

// switch back to the original blog
restore_current_blog( );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will have to look into this solution at a future date. I had to move on with the project due to time constraints but ended up just doing it without using 'attachment_url_to_postid'. Ultimately this had to do with a greater image sizing issue, which was solved by requesting the client send SVGs instead of JPGs. :/